# "Алкаш в бакалее"

Tags: общие-вопросы, литература

"Но друг и учитель - алкаш в бакалее - 
Сказал, что семиты - простые евреи."

Это фрагмент одной из ранних песен Владимира Высоцкого. Мне непонятно, почему "алкаш в бакалее"? Разве в СССР алкогольные напитки продавались в бакалее?

Текст песни Высоцкого http://www.moskva.fm/artist/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/song_948736

Comment: Наверное, всё-таки "алкаш", который работет "в бакалее" (в бакалейном отделе продовольственного магазина).

Comment: «Разве в СССР алкогольные напитки продавались в бакалее?» Странно связывать этот вопрос с проблемой русского языка.

Comment: Это текст песни известного барда, поэта. Хочется понять все смысловые нюансы этого текста. Кто сможет, ответит, надеюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему "алкаш в бакалее"? Потому что "в бакалее" рифмуется с "евреи". При всё уважении к творчеству Высоцкого с рифмовкой он особо не заморачивался, упирая на общий смысл и подачу. Алкаш в бакалее мог работать, стоять в очереди, жить в доме, где находился бакалейный магазин, для понимания песни это не важно. Главное что б было понятно, доверия сей источник информации не заслуживает.

Comment: Спасибо, Марк Из !

Answer (score 1):

Это мог быть пьющий (по внешнему виду) продавец бакалейного отдела "гастронома" (или просто разговорчивый человек из очереди). В крупных городах так называли типовые магазины с несколькими наружными вывесками (и с соотв. отделами ручной продажи внутри): "гастрономия" (сыр, колбасы, масло),"бакалея" (крупы), "мясо", овощи и "вино".

Comment: Благодарю, Alex_ander !

Answer (score 1):

Меня один мой знакомый, с детства слушающий записи песен Высоцкого, уверял, что в советские времена существовало устойчивое словосочетание "алкаш-бакалея". Думаю, это неправда. Скорее всего, "алкаш" из песни работал грузчиком (не продавцом) в бакалее. Тогда всё сходится. Да и рифма к слову "евреи" хорошая, конечно.
Ответы мне помогли. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, устойчивое словосочетание "алкаш с бакалеи" мною впервые было услышано в конце 60-х.В те времена были специализированные бакалейные магазины и отделы в продуктовых магазинах. В каждом отделе были свои грузчики или подсобные рабочие. Самыми престижными были отделы гастрономии и вино-водочных изделий, так как помимо ежемесячной зарплаты грузчикам негласно доплачивали три-пять рублей в смену за "тяжкий труд" и выполнения поручений не входивших в должностные обязанности. Да и за определённое молчание тоже. Ни для кого не секрет, что в некоторых продуктовых магазинах иногда появлялся дефицитный товар, который расторопные грузчики(они же подсобники)продавали по завышенной цене,без очереди с чёрного хода.
 А в вино-водочных отделах продавцы торговали дешёвым портвейном из "под прилавка, а работяги с чёрного хода, иногда с ведома продавца или заведующего. Особенно выгодно было до 11:00и после 19:00,официального времени продажи алкоголя.Для грузчиков это был Клондайк и многие были уже в то время достаточно состоятельными в материальном плане.
А в бакалейных отделах как правило ни каких доплат грузчикам не было. Редко в каком отделе продавали коньяк и шампанское, и ещё реже пиво. В такие отделы на работу грузчиком шли неохотно,-приработка ни какого. А если человек ещё к тому же был пьющий, то пропивалась зарплата и так совсем небольшая(90-110 р/месяц).
Видимо поэтому Высоцкий и употребил этот термин, "алкаш с бакалеи" в своей песне..

Comment: отец Святослав: «Редко в каком отделе продавали коньяк и шампанское, и ещё реже пиво» . ============== Чудеса!

Comment: Песня  Высоцкого написана в 1963 г., а вы впервые услышали выражение в конце 60-х. Не думаю, что это совпадение.